# escaping characters when passing JSON to aws secretsmanager

Tags: bash, escaping, jq, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I have tried to write a script that updates AWS secrets.  Yes, the `update-secret` command already does this, but that will overwrite existing secrets instead of merging them w/ the new content.

For example, suppose **my-environment/my-application/secrets** has the following content:

```
{ "db_1_pwd": "secret"}
```

If I run my script, like this:

```
>> update_secret my-environment/my-application/secrets '{"db_2_pwd": "secreter"}'
```

I would expect the new content to be:

```
{ "db_1_pwd": "secret", "db_2_pwd": "secreter"}
```

Instead, the new content winds up being this (unescaped) string:

```
"{\"db_1_pwd\":\"secret\",\"db_2_pwd\":\"secreter\"}"
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

SECRET_ID=$1
SECRET_STRING=$2

EXISTING_SECRET=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_ID | jq '.SecretString | fromjson'`
NEW_SECRET=`echo $EXISTING_SECRET $SECRET_STRING | jq  -s 'add tostring'`

echo $NEW_SECRET  # this is printed out for debug purposes

aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_ID --secret-string $NEW_SECRET
```

Note that it does print out `"{\"db_1_pwd\":\"secret\",\"db_2_pwd\":\"secreter\"}"` in the echo statement and if I type this on the command line:

```
>> aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id my-environment/my-application/secrets --secret-string "{\"db_1_pwd\":\"secret\",\"db_2_pwd\":\"secreter\"}"
```

it works.

Clearly the script is having issues w/ escaping the quotation marks.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

(*It's probably something to do w/ bash as opposed to AWS*)

Comment: What is your question? It looks like whatever you have works

Comment: @Inian - My script didn't work.  It sets **my-environment/my-application/secrets**  to the *string*: `"{\"db_1_pwd\":\"secret\",\"db_2_pwd\":\"secreter\"}"` instead of setting it to the *object*: `{"db_1_pwd": "secret", "db_2_pwd": "secreter"}`.

@Philippe's answer below, which wraps `$NEW_SECRET` in quotes works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following script worked for me :

```
#!/bin/sh

SECRET_ID=$1
SECRET_STRING=$2
EXISTING_SECRET=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_ID | jq '.SecretString | fromjson'`
NEW_SECRET=`echo "$EXISTING_SECRET $SECRET_STRING" | jq  -s add`
aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_ID --secret-string "$NEW_SECRET"
```

Comment: @Phiippe - I tried many different things but somehow I must not have tried that.  Your example works for me too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the output format (json by default):

aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "mysecretid" --query SecretString --output text